# What exactly does LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN do?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, memberof

I have read about `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` do on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx a few times and Googled but I can't get a grasp on what it does.

This is what MSDN says but I do not get it. What does "**walks the chain of ancestry**" mean?

> This rule is limited to filters that apply to the DN. This is a special "extended" match operator that walks the chain of ancestry in objects all the way to the root until it finds a match.

No matter what I do all of my searches return the same data.

```
<GC://DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=one,DC=some,DC=company,DC=com));name;subtree
```

or

```
<GC://DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=one,DC=some,DC=company,DC=com));name;subtree
```

I understand that both of them will search the subtree of the GC for all user's that are a member of the group `CN=one,DC=some,DC=company,DC=com`. What I cannot figure out is what does the second one do differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the first one only finds objects that have a direct membership, where as the second one will recursively find nested membership.

Given the following groups:

```
Group A is a member of Group B
Group B is a member of Group C
```

Querying `Group A` with the first method will just return `Group B`. Using the second method would return `Group B` and `Group C`